# Searching for solution to dynamically create endpoints in ruby sinatra by reading a file without restarting the web server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, puma

Trying to develop a framework to read from a file in text or json format for request and response and create dynamic endpoints to using ruby Sintra. Using web server as Puma for the web app deployment over the Kubernetes cluster.

Tried doing it through the external app.rb file generation but that would require restart of the server on the modification of the file or redeployment of the overall container altogether.

Comment: This is an example of so called "XY problem". Could you explain the problem per se (with the example of source file in question) and why did you decide Sinatra should be used here, please?

Comment: Konstantin is correct. The problem that has been described here sounds very odd. The answer is most likely "that's not the right way to approach this problem," hence [XY](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: This isn’t a proper stackoverflow question. You need to learn how to ask questions here first, honestly, it’s helpful for you and everyone when you do it the right way. I googled this guide for you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask